# Return group_concat with multiple rows

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a `orderLine` table, where orders are attached to products. So my orderLine table can look like this:

orderID as coupled to orderLineId as a foreign key.

```
orderID   productID
1         2
2         1
2         2
```

And my `order` table is like this:

```
orderLineId      userID
1                 1
1                 1
2                 1
```

But if I do the `GROUP_CONCAT` query:

```
SELECT orderLine.orderId,
       GROUP_CONCAT(orderLine.productId)
FROM orders
  INNER JOIN orderLine ON orders.orderLineId = orderLine.orderId
WHERE orders.orderId = 1
```

I get the result:

```
orderId, GROUP_CONCAT(orderLine.productId)
1       1,2,2
```

But I want to have:

```
orderId, GROUP_CONCAT(orderLine.productId)
1       1,2
2       2
```

Comment: Add GROUP BY orderLine.orderId (after the WHERE clause.)

Comment: It works @jarlh. Thanks mate!

Comment: Your data structure is messed up.  The `Orders` table should not have an `OrderLineId`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `GROUP BY orderLine.orderId` to get one row for each orderId:

```
SELECT orderLine.orderId,
       GROUP_CONCAT(orderLine.productId)
FROM orders
  INNER JOIN orderLine ON orders.orderLineId = orderLine.orderId
WHERE orders.orderId = 1
GROUP BY orderLine.orderId
```